# How do I replace part of a path in my web.config transform?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, web-config, web.config-transform

I am trying to perform a `web.config` transform in Visual Studio 2022 by modifying the `web.Debug.config` file.

Changing attributes on elements, removing elements and attributes, etc. is all very straightforward. But I've a read through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)) and I've done some Google searching, and I cannot figure out a way to replace part of a path string in my `web.config` file.

Given that I have lots of NLog `target` elements is there an easy way to replace the root path in the `fileName` and `archiveFileName` attributes for each?

Here is where I am coming from:

```
    <target xsi:type="File" name="seedDataLogFile"
            fileName="C:/ProductionPath/Logs/seedDataCurrent.json"
            archiveFileName="C:/ProductionPath/Logs/SeedDataArchive/{#}.json"
            archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Date" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" maxArchiveFiles="60"
            concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="false">
```

And here is where I want to go:

```
    <target xsi:type="File" name="seedDataLogFile"
            fileName="D:/DevelopmentPath/Logs/seedDataCurrent.json"
            archiveFileName="D:/DevelopmentPath/Logs/SeedDataArchive/{#}.json"
            archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Date" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" maxArchiveFiles="60"
            concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="false">
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use NLog-Config-variables for the Log-Directory. Then it is just a matter of updating the NLog-variable-value. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer